# How to make this example of pseudo-ducktyping type unambiguously without annotations

Tags: haskell, typeclass, duck-typing

I wanted to demonstrate the idea of statically verifiable duck typing in Haskell using `MultiParamTypeClasses`, but I am having trouble avoiding type ambiguity.

Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class HasBar a b where
    bar :: b -> a 

data Foo = Foo { barBool :: Bool } deriving (Show)

instance HasBar Bool Foo where
    bar = barBool

data Bazz = Bazz { barInt :: Int } deriving (Show)

instance HasBar Int Bazz where
    bar = barInt
```

When I load it into GHCi and try to do `bar (Foo True)` or `bar (Bazz 5)` I get a `Non type-variable argument` error and it suggests `FlexibleContexts`, which just changes the error to an ambiguity error. Now doing something like `False || bar (Foo True)` works fine. But that doesn't seem like it should be needed as `Foo` is only a member of the typeclass that returns a `Bool`.

It seems like the issue is something to do with the possibility of something like:

```
instance HasBar Int Foo where
    bar = const 5
```

Which would necessitate the types being ambiguous. But if there is just one instance I don't see why there are any issues preventing Haskell from finding out the type (do I need some sort of extension). If I can't do it that way then is there an alternative to `MultiParamTypeClasses` that only allows one instance and would allow for this pseudo-ducktyping type of thing to work?

Comment: btw: I don't think this is duck-typing at all - first you change the signature of `bar` between *ducks* and then you need the `instance`s - it's just polymorphism

Comment: @Carsten I was thinking l largely about automatic code generation. Where you would use duck typing in a (modified version of a) language like Python, and it would be converted to Haskell by automatically generating these "psuedo-ducktyping" classes and instances and what not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that it's not only looking for what it *sees* but what it can *know* - and there is the possibility for you to make an instance that will be `HasBar Int Foo` as well so it complains

You can get rid of this with either [`FunctionalDependencies`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) or [`TypeFamilies`](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families)

### using *functional dependencies*

the first extension is probably the way to go here (you don't have to change much of your code). You can basically tell GHCi, that the type `b` in your class/constraint will be enough to decide the type `a`.

if you change it to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

class HasBar a b | b -> a where
    bar :: b -> a
```

it'll work (you need the `FlexibleContexts` only in GHCi

```
λ> :set -XFlexibleContexts
λ> bar (Foo True)
True
```

### using *type families*

In case you are interested here is the same thing with type-families and associated types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class HasBar a where
  type Bar a :: *
  bar :: a -> Bar a

data Foo = Foo { barBool :: Bool } deriving (Show)

instance HasBar Foo where
  type Bar Foo = Bool
  bar = barBool

data Bazz = Bazz { barInt :: Int } deriving (Show)

instance HasBar Bazz where
  type  Bar Bazz = Int
  bar = barInt
```

note that you don't need the `MultiParamTypeClasses` any more